# How to show results of multiple table into one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my code, but the result is blank.

```
SELECT TOP 1 grade_el.grade_ID, time_el.time_id, subjects_el.IDno, subjects_el.subj_name 
FROM grade_el,
     subjects_el,
     scheduling_el,
     time_el
WHERE grade_el.grade_ID = 1 
  AND time_el.time_id = 0001
  AND subjects_el.subj_name <> scheduling_el.subj_name 
ORDER BY rnd(subjects_el.IDno)
```

Can someone help me, please.

Comment: Missing join conditions?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result when having TOP 1 and ORDER BY removed.

Comment: seems that you want a cross join (cartesian product) between four table grade_el, subjects_el, scheduling_el, time_el this is true?

or you have misside join condition and 

loooking to you code  could be that you don't have grade_el.grade_ID  = 1  or ime_el.time_id = 0001  (strange format why 0001 and not 1 or '0001' )
or subjects_el.subj_name <> scheduling_el.subj_name

Comment: join condition?? i think so. im newbie about this thing. can you help me??

Comment: you will need this -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: ok ok. i'll check it out. .thank you

Comment: for us to help you, please provide a small amount of data from each table then we might see how those tables relate. basically right now the equation is: no data = no visibility = no help

Comment: ok sir. i have a 4 tables. grade table,subject table, time table, subject table and sched table. actually what i was trying to do was to insert the result from this query